# What is diffrence between SPContentDatabaseSequence and SPContentDatabaseSequence2

Tags: 2013, central-administration, upgrade, content-database, schema

When i am inside Mange Content Database settings  page inside my farm, i see 3 different Schema Version for my content db as follows:
[image]

I understand the first listing that is
 Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence Current Schema Version: 15.0.145.0

But i am confused what are other two?

Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence2 Current Schema Version: 15.0.14.0, Maximum Schema Version: 15.0.14.0

Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabase Current Schema Version: 15.0.4551.1001, Maximum Schema Version: 15.0.4551.1001

Can anyone explain me whats the difference.

Thank You

Comment: I think you should mark Waqas's the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sequences and actions are events that occur when you upgrade Microsoft SharePoint Products and Technologies.

The upgrade process consists primarily of sequences and actions.

- A sequence may be repeated if there are multiple items of the same
  type. For example, a sequence may be repeated if there are multiple
  content databases, multiple Web Applications, or multiple Application
  Pools.
- Each action has an associated TargetSchemaVersion number. The
  TargetSchemaVersion number is recorded in Microsoft SQL Server after
  an action is completed successfully on a given object.
- The TargetSchemaVersion numbers for most sequences is recorded in the
  objects table of the configuration database. However, the
  SPContentDatabase TargetSchemaVersion numbers are recorded in the
  content databases.

What are you seeing the headings of Content DB Sequences 1 & 2, each sequence have set of operations which you can see from the below KB article. Even this is for 2003 but still valid for 2013. one more thing you seeing number 15 in version number because you are on sharepoint 2013.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948780

Comment: Waqas thank you very much for this info, but the schema number SPContentDatabaseSequence2 Current Schema Version: 15.0.14.0 what does that represent. What version or what CU is that. I couldn't find any info about that number.

Comment: these are actions numbers...1st number i beleive represnet the SharePoint version i.e 15 is for sharepoint 2013...The third number in the versioning schema is the schema number for the action. In this case, the schema number for the FixSecurityCorruptions action is 150. 

The fourth number in the versioning schema is the phase in which an action executes. A zero value indicates that there is a single phase in an action. Typically, x.x.x.0 and x.x.x.5 appear when there are two phases. If there are more than two phases, you will see a pattern that resembles x.x.x.1000, x.x.x.2000, x.x.x3000.